# Any solution for CORS?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, cors, .net-6.0

Trying to solve a problem with CORS. I think I've tried all the ways... but none work.

I use react + .net 6

Profiles section in launchSettings.json in .net app

```
  "profiles": {
    "FlightArrivalsStat.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5144",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

in programm.cs I added

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

In the react app, I tried to use both one and all ways at once:

Using craco:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    proxy: {
        '/api/**' :{
            target: 'http://localhost:5144',
            pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
        }
    }
}
```

Added `"proxy": "http://localhost:5144"` to package.json

Create axios like:

```
export default axios.create({

    baseURL: "http://localhost:5144/api",
    
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    }
});
```

Request is very simple:

```
await axios.get<ArrivalArray>('schedule', {params});
```

In browser console i getting following message in all cases:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:5144/api/schedule?station=DME&date=2023-08-22T09:26:55.437Z&range=60'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Same issue for https...
After googling tons information can i  ask, what i'm doing wrong and what missed?

Comment: Is it failing in all cases or for specific calls? CORS treat POSTs as either simple or complex depending on the data sent. See preflight checks here: https://codedamn.com/news/backend/how-to-fix-cors-error

Comment: what's the exacr error message you are getting in the browser console

Comment: @UjjawalKumar I added error message , please take a look

Answer (score 1):

> Same issue for https... After googling tons information can i ask,
> what i'm doing wrong and what missed?

Based on your scenario and configuration, it seems that your client-side configuration are correct.  Apart from that,  preflight request failure can be caused by couple of reasons, for instance, if the request URL contains any trailing slash `/` other than your email origin or URL? Let's say, your target is `http://localhost:5144/login` but in your request it is passing like `http://localhost:5144/login/` can results CORS. Please double check that.

Another important point is that, hows your controller? Does it has any CORS attribute on top of that? Like [EnableCors("Your CORS policy Name")],

Furthermore, please set following property to true within your launchsettings.json file in order to respond preflight request accordingly.

```
 "windowsAuthentication": true,
 "anonymousAuthentication": true,
```

Backend CORS Configurtaion:

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_corsapppolicy";
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name:MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5144") //Should be your client side incoming request URL
                .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET");// Include all http verb you want to allow
            });
    });
```

Use Middleware Reference:

```
app.UseCors("MyAllowSpecificOrigins")
```

Set Controller CORS attribute:

You can [enable your controller with CORS policy attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#enable-cors-with-attributes) you have created as following:

```
[EnableCors("_corsapppolicy")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "Your value 1", "Your value 2" };
}
```

Alternative Way:

```
var corsAppPolicy = "_corsapppolicy";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsAppPolicy,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

Register Middleware:

```
app.UseCors(corsAppPolicy);
```

**Note:** Please refer to this [official document for CORS middleware configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware) and also [check controller attribute for CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#enable-cors-with-attributes)